# trying to understand wrapall()

Tags: jquery, wrapall

I have done reading on wrapall() and I think it may be the solution I need.  Give this structure:

```
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

I would like to end up with this structure:

```
<ul>
<div class="class1">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>
<div class="class2">
<li></li>
<li></li>
</div>
</ul>
```

I haven't the slightest how to accomplish this.  I've read some example of wrapall but none that I can adapt in this manner

Comment: That's not valid HTML. You can't do this.

Comment: Your desired result isn't actually valid. You can't just drop a `div` in the middle of a `ul`.

Comment: You can eventually wrap the desired elements inside a `<ul>` (that's inside a `<li>`)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('ul li').slice(0,2).wrapAll('<ul></ul>').closest('ul').wrap('<li />');
```

Which results in:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
             <li>1</li>
             <li>2</li>
         </ul>
     </li>    
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7qrdp/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = $('li');
do { $(a.slice(0,2)).wrapAll('<li class="two"><ul></ul></li>'); }
while( (a = a.slice(2) ).length>0 );
```

which results in:

```
<ul>
    <li class="two">
       <ul>
          <li>a1</li>
          <li>a2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="two">
       <ul>
         <li>b1</li>
         <li>b2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```